# Invalid syntax in list comprehension on Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

```
selection_list = ['list', 'with', 'values', 'from', 'countries', 'column']

for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['country'] not in selection_list:
            df.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

Now this code works, but I wanted to try to rebuild this code into a list comprehension, just to see if I could make it work. Turns out I can't.

```
df = df.drop(index, inplace=True) for index, row in df.iterrows() if row['country'] not in selection_list
```

Now I can't figure out why this is not working, so I was wondering if anyone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong here.

I know that for a list comprehension I usually should put brackets around the list comprehension, but I want my dataframe to remain a dataframe, not turn into a list.

Comment: You're missing the outer brackets `[` `]` for the list comprehension. And the `if` part should be after the `for` part.

Comment: `df = df.loc[df['country'].isin(selection_list)]` might be better for you

Comment: @Matthias I placed the if after the for part but that did not help. Also, I really want this data to remain a dataframe, and placing brackets seems to convert the dataframe to a list.

Comment: @Chris Thank you, that seems to be a more clever solution to what I did. However, it still doesn't really answer my question, since I still don't understand why a list comprehension in my example won't work.